# What is the techniques to implement Visual Web Scraper?

Tags: screen-scraping, web-crawler

I'm going to build a visual web scraper. The most important feature the software required is "visual" like http://mozenda.com/.
The software create a tool like web-browser not only allow user to browse a webpage, perform some tasks as authenticate, click links, make searching, ... but also can track all these tasks.
Does anyone know the techniques to implement this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[import.io](https://import.io/) is way to go! It's free ATM

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

With IRobotSoft Visual Web Scraper, you are able to visually record web scraping actions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kinds of tasks you are looking for...  but this sounds like a Firefox extension you are trying to build and automate.

I would look at those docs to see how you can attach to the main browser window and track those click and keyboard actions.

Comment: Thanks all.
I have just found the components called IWebBrowser and BHO which should be useful.